# Converting string to floating number Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a issue using variable in if condition. I have three variable where one is a string type and two more in Json. Here settings.DecimalDigits value is 2 or anything more than 2.

```
var controlValue = integer + '.' + mantissa;
controlValue = parseFloat(controlValue).toFixed(settings.DecimalDigits);
```

integer & mantissa will have a certain value which is stored in controlValue as string. **controlValue** is then compared with other two variables (**settings.MaxValue & settings.MinValue**) in IF condition but its not going through condition as it type is **string type**

```
if (controlValue > settings.MaxValue)
                controlValue = settings.MaxValue;

            if (controlValue < settings.MinValue)
                controlValue = settings.MinValue;
```

In my parsing all three variables will have three values in floating type

controlValue = 123.23 or 123.00 
settings.MaxValue = 99.99 
settings.MinValue = -99.99 
 Please help so that the parsing goes through the **IF Condition**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jfriend00's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13282912/16587) helped me solve my problem. Solution below:

```
            var controlValue = e.target.value; //get value from input
            controlValue = Number(controlValue); //Converting the string to number

            // Number format parses through if condition
            if (controlValue > settings.MaxValue)
                controlValue = Number(settings.MaxValue);
            if (controlValue < settings.MinValue)
                controlValue = Number(settings.MinValue);

            // if the value is having a mantissa 00. It will be rejected by Number() function. So next line its converted again to string format using .toFixed() function. 

            var controlValue = controlValue.toFixed(settings.DecimalDigits);

            // Splitting the value into two parts integer and mantissa 
            integer = controlValue.split('.')[0];
            if (typeof integer == 'undefined' || integer == null || integer == "" || isNaN(integer))
                integer = 0;

           // settings.DecimalDigits is the variable to set any default number of mantissa required to appear. 
            mantissa = controlValue.split('.')[1];
            if (typeof mantissa == 'undefined') {
                mantissa = "";
                for (i = 0; i < settings.DecimalDigits; i++)
                    mantissa += '0';
            }

            // Finally you have the result
            controlValue = integer + '.' + mantissa;
```

Comment: Hmmm.  So, I help you figure this out.  Nobody else provides any help.  You take some info from my answer and incorporate it into your solution (a good thing) and then you end up taking away any credit from my answer so I receive no reputation credit at all for helping you.  As you're relatively new here, perhaps you don't understand how SO works, but it usually works better if you reward those who help you.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00, I tried clicking on the vote up for your answer. It gives a box saying you need 15 reputation for doing that :) Anyways thanks a lot man... But the answer didn't help much. However found a work around.:)

Comment: Yes, when you are such low reputation, the only way you can reward an answerer is by accepting their answer.  You can earn more reputation by answering other people's questions.

Answer (score 2):

`.toFixed()` turns your number back into a string.  If you want it back to a number again, then you need to use parseFloat on it.  There are probably better ways to do this, but building on your existing code, you would make `controlValue` a number that would work in your `if` statement by calling `parseFloat()` again like this:

```
var controlValue = integer + '.' + mantissa;
controlValue = parseFloat(parseFloat(controlValue).toFixed(settings.DecimalDigits));
```

FYI, it might make more sense to just handle the number entirely as a number rather than go back and forth to strings several times:

```
var controlValue = parseFloat(integer + '.' + mantissa);
var filter = Math.pow(10, settings.DecimalDigits);
controlValue = Math.round(controlValue * filter) / filter;
```

or perhaps even just this:

```
var controlValue = parseFloat(integer + '.' + mantissa.toString().substr(0, settings.DecimalDigits));
```

Comment: Cool....:) I breaking my head for this simple solution. lols... Thanks @jfriend00

Comment: @ShishirKumarM - I added a few more options to my answer.

Comment: I am looking for a result which returns the result as 213.00, Where the number should be followed **".00"**. Could you please help me out with this ? The result will return mantissa if it is other than 00 after "."

Comment: Hurray... I coded a work around for this problem.. But sad part is I can post the answer only after 5 hours from now :(